# How to save as xls from mysql fetching data to www/data/ folder using php?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am new to PHP development. I am creating excel.xls using the mentioned header information, whereas it is saving as xls at default download folder. Actually, when I click export link, this test.xls file should be saved to www/data/ folder instead of downloading it.
How can I give path for new location to save file using PHP dynamically?

## code as follows:

```
$file = "test.xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=$file");
```

### code end

Please help if possible.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Balraj

Answer (score 0):

You can use **file_put_contents** in PHP.

```
$file = "path/test.xls";
$data = "Keep your data into this variable";
file_put_contents($file,$data);
```

file_put_contents is wrapper for fopen,fwrite,fclose.For more information check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great help. I could the file to www/data folder, whereas at the same time downloading also takesplace. How to avoid a download while copying a file? thanks in advance

Comment: $file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pypl/demo.xls";
$data = "Keep your data into this variable<br><table border='1'  bgcolor='green'><tr bgcolor='yellow'><td rowspan=2>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
file_put_contents($file,$data); the above code is used for file saving, but downloading also takesplace while executing this

Comment: remove the header

Comment: please accept this answer you missed it @Balrajswamy

Comment: you can see the tick mark just click that to change green color